How to say "return the favour" in the sense of getting back at someone?
I was watching a TV program where a bunch of adolescents said to each other, "I can't believe that they humiliated us! We need to do the same to them."
What would be the translation of "returning the favour" in this unfriendly sense?
On Google I can only find a translation of the positive sense, i.e. returning a good favour - 報答.


What would be the translation of "returning the favour" in this unfriendly sense?

"报复" - retaliate, revenge, or get even with. It is defined as committing a harmful action against a person or group in response to a grievance, or to do harm the same or similar in return for harm done.

see BKRS: 以其人之道,还治其人之身 deal with a man as he deals with you; pay sb. back in his own coin
以眼还眼，以牙还牙 an eye for an eye and a tooth for a tooth; return blow for blow
名

@user6065Yes, they both are valid as both mean "报复 - return the favor".

I don't think the non-literal, satirical version of I'll return the favour someday will work in Chinese:
日后我会报恩的。
because 报恩 means return something good.
But you could say the unsatirical:
日后我会报仇的。

"returning the favor" is a common English expression, it is better to translate it as a Chinese saying or idiom

禮尚往來 比喻被施以怎樣的行為，即以怎樣的行為回報 (gift giving should go both ways = return the favor)

以牙還牙 比喻对方怎样来,就怎样反击 (a tooth for a tooth = return the favor)



How about 以怨報怨 ? This is native Chinese when 以牙還牙 is more or less imported.

Just use "还以颜色". Because it isn't that escalated, even in a negative way.
If it's really serious, use "以牙还牙"。
